# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, in Azure function 1

Tags: c#, azure-functions, dynamics-crm, .net-4.8

I am getting following error while using **microsoft.powerplatform.dataverse.client** nuget package in my `Azure function(type 1, .net framework 4.8)`. I am using above nuget package to retrieve information from `Ms Dynamics CRM`.
This error only comes at runtime, not during compile time. Please help for the same.

***Error:***

```cs
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried adding `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`, Version=3.1.8.0 in solution.
I could not downgrade it to Version 3.1.0.0 because `microsoft.powerplatform.dataverse.client` package needs Version >=3.1.8.0.

Comment: why you use v1? Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client supports newer versions of azure functions

Comment: As per my knowledge, Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client does not support with .net6. We dont want to go with .netcore3 because it is been discontinued in Azure function. We have only two option V1 or V4. V4 does not support Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.  if you have any solution other than OData to connect CRM from V4. please let me know.

Comment: it supports .net 6

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to Install and use the Nuget Package `**microsoft.powerplatform.dataverse.client**.

- Created an Azure Function with `.NET Framework v1`.

[image]

- when I tried to add **microsoft.powerplatform.dataverse.client** NuGet Package, got the below error.

[image]

- As suggested in the error message, added `Newtonsoft.Json version 13.0.1` package.
- Now I am able to build and install the `microsoft.powerplatform.dataverse.client` package without any issue but got the compile time Assembly warning.

```cs
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.24 requires Newtonsoft.Json (= 9.0.1) but version Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1 was resolved.
```

[image]

- Even installed the NuGet package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` which you have installed as an add on.
- I am able to run and access the Function locally without any issue.

***My .csproj file***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v1</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client" Version="1.0.26" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***Local Output***
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help. Problem only coming when you are trying to use Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client, mean when I am creating service client for crm connection in code than only it is giving error on run time. if I comment that service code, it works fine.                                                                                                                 ServiceClient conn = new ServiceClient($@"Url={organizationUri};AuthType=ClientSecret;ClientId={clientId};ClientSecret={clientSecret};;RequireNewInstance=true");

Comment: Will check and let you know.

Comment: Could you please share the code file which you are write the above code?

Comment: Have you added the namespace`using Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client;`
 in the code file?